# Geofence to get all place id's inside the fixed Kms in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, geofencing

I'm in need to get all placeId's inside the fixed kms circle from the current location. I don't know this could be achievable in flutter, but GeoFencing concept works for this I guess, but didn't seen any blogs or solutions to achieve this in Flutter, looking for your help to save my time, as its an urgent need.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this library [backgroundfetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) to call a function even if the app is closed.
The next step is to check if that method is in Latlng bonds or not.

Comment: but this isn't need to be in background.. i have to get all place id's and send to backend, that's all the process